# Laravel Unknown column 'name' in 'field list'" on Register

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to register a user on my table, when I click register I get returned an error "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'name' in 'field list'" I am running adminLTE and laravel-users package. When I change the name from

web.php:

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::resource('accounts', 'AccountsController');
Route::resource('gateways', 'GatewaysController');
Route::resource('messages', 'MessagesController');
Route::resource('recipients', 'RecipientsController');
Route::resource('routers', 'RoutersController');
Route::resource('sources', 'SourcesController');
Route::get('/users', 'UsersManagementController@index   ');

// APP Routes Below
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web', 'namespace' => '\App\Http\Controllers'], function () {
    Route::resource('users', 'UsersManagementController', [
        'names' => [
            'index'   => 'users',
            'destroy' => 'user.destroy',
        ],
    ]);
});

Route::middleware(['web', 'auth'])->group(function () {
    Route::post('search-users', '\App\Http\Controllers\UsersManagementController@search')->name('search-users');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

While trying to fix the problem I found a generated PHP file located: \file\storage\framework\views\ which has an error showing on "$__env" on line 1 & $errors on line 53 (both undefined errors). When I change the

```
<?php $__env->startSection('adminlte_css'); ?>
    <?php echo $__env->yieldPushContent('css'); ?>
    <?php echo $__env->yieldContent('css'); ?>
<?php $__env->stopSection(); ?>

<?php $__env->startSection('classes_body', 'register-page'); ?>

<?php ( $login_url = View::getSection('login_url') ?? config('adminlte.login_url', 'login') ); ?>
<?php ( $register_url = View::getSection('register_url') ?? config('adminlte.register_url', 'register') ); ?>
<?php ( $dashboard_url = View::getSection('dashboard_url') ?? config('adminlte.dashboard_url', 'home') ); ?>

<?php if(config('adminlte.use_route_url', false)): ?>
    <?php ( $login_url = $login_url ? route($login_url) : '' ); ?>
    <?php ( $register_url = $register_url ? route($register_url) : '' ); ?>
    <?php ( $dashboard_url = $dashboard_url ? route($dashboard_url) : '' ); ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php ( $login_url = $login_url ? url($login_url) : '' ); ?>
    <?php ( $register_url = $register_url ? url($register_url) : '' ); ?>
    <?php ( $dashboard_url = $dashboard_url ? url($dashboard_url) : '' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php $__env->startSection('body'); ?>
    <div class="register-box">
        <div class="register-logo">
            <a href="<?php echo e($dashboard_url); ?>"><?php echo config('adminlte.logo', '<b>Admin</b>LTE'); ?></a>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body register-card-body">
                <p class="login-box-msg"><?php echo e(__('adminlte::adminlte.register_message')); ?></p>
                <form action="<?php echo e($register_url); ?>" method="post">
                    <?php echo e(csrf_field()); ?>

<!--                    New code added here -->

                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control <?php echo e($errors->has('first_name') ? 'is-invalid' : ''); ?>" value="<?php echo e(old('first_name')); ?>"
                               placeholder="<?php echo e(__('adminlte::adminlte.first_name')); ?>" autofocus>
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <div class="input-group-text">
                                <span class="fas fa-user"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <?php if($errors->has('first_name')): ?>
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                <strong><?php echo e($errors->first('first_name')); ?></strong>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>

                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <input type="text" name="last_name" class="form-control <?php echo e($errors->has('last_name') ? 'is-invalid' : ''); ?>" value="<?php echo e(old('last_name')); ?>"
                               placeholder="<?php echo e(__('adminlte::adminlte.last_name')); ?>" autofocus>
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <div class="input-group-text">
                                <span class="fas fa-user"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <?php if($errors->has('last_name')): ?>
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                <strong><?php echo e($errors->first('last_name')); ?></strong>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>

                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <input type="text" name="business_name" class="form-control <?php echo e($errors->has('business_name') ? 'is-invalid' : ''); ?>" value="<?php echo e(old('business_name')); ?>"
                               placeholder="<?php echo e(__('adminlte::adminlte.business_name')); ?>" autofocus>
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <div class="input-group-text">
                                <span class="fas fa-user"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <?php if($errors->has('business_name')): ?>
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                <strong><?php echo e($errors->first('business_name')); ?></strong>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>

                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <input type="text" name="msidn" class="form-control <?php echo e($errors->has('msidn') ? 'is-invalid' : ''); ?>" value="<?php echo e(old('msidn')); ?>"
                               placeholder="<?php echo e(__('adminlte::adminlte.msidn')); ?>" autofocus>
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <div class="input-group-text">
                                <span class="fas fa-user"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <?php if($errors->has('msidn')): ?>
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                <strong><?php echo e($errors->first('msidn')); ?></strong>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>


<!--                    New code finishes here -->

                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control <?php echo e($errors->has('email') ? 'is-invalid' : ''); ?>" value="<?php echo e(old('email')); ?>"
                               placeholder="<?php echo e(__('adminlte::adminlte.email')); ?>">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <div class="input-group-text">
                                <span class="fas fa-envelope"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php if($errors->has('email')): ?>
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                <strong><?php echo e($errors->first('email')); ?></strong>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control <?php echo e($errors->has('password') ? 'is-invalid' : ''); ?>"
                               placeholder="<?php echo e(__('adminlte::adminlte.password')); ?>">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <div class="input-group-text">
                                <span class="fas fa-lock"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php if($errors->has('password')): ?>
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                <strong><?php echo e($errors->first('password')); ?></strong>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" class="form-control <?php echo e($errors->has('password_confirmation') ? 'is-invalid' : ''); ?>"
                               placeholder="<?php echo e(__('adminlte::adminlte.retype_password')); ?>">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <div class="input-group-text">
                                <span class="fas fa-lock"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php if($errors->has('password_confirmation')): ?>
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                <strong><?php echo e($errors->first('password_confirmation')); ?></strong>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">
                        <?php echo e(__('adminlte::adminlte.register')); ?>

                    </button>
                </form>
                <p class="mt-2 mb-1">
                    <a href="<?php echo e($login_url); ?>">
                        <?php echo e(__('adminlte::adminlte.i_already_have_a_membership')); ?>

                    </a>
                </p>
            </div><!-- /.card-body -->
        </div><!-- /.card -->
    </div><!-- /.register-box -->
<?php $__env->stopSection(); ?>

<?php $__env->startSection('adminlte_js'); ?>
    <script src="<?php echo e(asset('vendor/adminlte/dist/js/adminlte.min.js')); ?>"></script>
    <?php echo $__env->yieldPushContent('js'); ?>
    <?php echo $__env->yieldContent('js'); ?>
<?php $__env->stopSection(); ?>

<?php echo $__env->make('adminlte::master', \Illuminate\Support\Arr::except(get_defined_vars(), ['__data', '__path']))->render(); ?><?php /**PATH C:\file\vendor\jeroennoten\laravel-adminlte\src/../resources/views/register.blade.php ENDPATH**/ ?>
```

register.blade.php

```
@extends('adminlte::master')

@section('adminlte_css')
    @stack('css')
    @yield('css')
@stop

@section('classes_body', 'register-page')

@php( $login_url = View::getSection('login_url') ?? config('adminlte.login_url', 'login') )
@php( $register_url = View::getSection('register_url') ?? config('adminlte.register_url', 'register') )
@php( $dashboard_url = View::getSection('dashboard_url') ?? config('adminlte.dashboard_url', 'home') )

@if (config('adminlte.use_route_url', false))
    @php( $login_url = $login_url ? route($login_url) : '' )
    @php( $register_url = $register_url ? route($register_url) : '' )
    @php( $dashboard_url = $dashboard_url ? route($dashboard_url) : '' )
@else
    @php( $login_url = $login_url ? url($login_url) : '' )
    @php( $register_url = $register_url ? url($register_url) : '' )
    @php( $dashboard_url = $dashboard_url ? url($dashboard_url) : '' )
@endif

@section('body')
    <div class="register-box">
        <div class="register-logo">
            <a href="{{ $dashboard_url }}">{!! config('adminlte.logo', '<b>Admin</b>LTE') !!}</a>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body register-card-body">
                <p class="login-box-msg">{{ __('adminlte::adminlte.register_message') }}</p>
                <form action="{{ $register_url }}" method="post">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}

                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control {{ $errors->has('name') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}" value="{{ old('name') }}"
                               placeholder="{{ __('adminlte::adminlte.full_name') }}" autofocus>
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <div class="input-group-text">
                                <span class="fas fa-user"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        @if ($errors->has('name'))
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                            </div>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control {{ $errors->has('email') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}" value="{{ old('email') }}"
                               placeholder="{{ __('adminlte::adminlte.email') }}">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <div class="input-group-text">
                                <span class="fas fa-envelope"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        @if ($errors->has('email'))
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                            </div>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control {{ $errors->has('password') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}"
                               placeholder="{{ __('adminlte::adminlte.password') }}">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <div class="input-group-text">
                                <span class="fas fa-lock"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        @if ($errors->has('password'))
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                            </div>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" class="form-control {{ $errors->has('password_confirmation') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}"
                               placeholder="{{ __('adminlte::adminlte.retype_password') }}">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <div class="input-group-text">
                                <span class="fas fa-lock"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        @if ($errors->has('password_confirmation'))
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                <strong>{{ $errors->first('password_confirmation') }}</strong>
                            </div>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">
                        {{ __('adminlte::adminlte.register') }}
                    </button>
                </form>
                <p class="mt-2 mb-1">
                    <a href="{{ $login_url }}">
                        {{ __('adminlte::adminlte.i_already_have_a_membership') }}
                    </a>
                </p>
            </div><!-- /.card-body -->
        </div><!-- /.card -->
    </div><!-- /.register-box -->
@stop

@section('adminlte_js')
    <script src="{{ asset('vendor/adminlte/dist/js/adminlte.min.js') }}"></script>
    @stack('js')
    @yield('js')
@stop
```

Here is the error log:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'name' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Name , laravel@test.nz, $2y$10$pyXa3roQY/YscDzwkrrSkO9pgYu7cSACdbLf/xq6RXh2GxG.tIz56, 2020-05-18 23:12:45, 2020-05-18 23:12:45)) in file C:\Users\Name \Desktop\\\\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php on line 671

#0 C:\Users\Name \Desktop\\\\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php(631): Illuminate\Database\Connection->runQueryCallback('insert into `us...', Array, Object(Closure))
```

Laravel-users uses a controller called UsersManagementController which is:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class UsersManagementController extends Controller
{
    private $_authEnabled;
    private $_rolesEnabled;
    private $_rolesMiddlware;
    private $_rolesMiddleWareEnabled;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_authEnabled = config('laravelusers.authEnabled');
        $this->_rolesEnabled = config('laravelusers.rolesEnabled');
        $this->_rolesMiddlware = config('laravelusers.rolesMiddlware');
        $this->_rolesMiddleWareEnabled = config('laravelusers.rolesMiddlwareEnabled');

        if ($this->_authEnabled) {
            $this->middleware('auth');
        }

        if ($this->_rolesEnabled && $this->_rolesMiddleWareEnabled) {
            $this->middleware($this->_rolesMiddlware);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $pagintaionEnabled = config('laravelusers.enablePagination');

        if ($pagintaionEnabled) {
            $users = config('laravelusers.defaultUserModel')::paginate(config('laravelusers.paginateListSize'));
        } else {
            $users = config('laravelusers.defaultUserModel')::all();
        }

        $data = [
            'users'             => $users,
            'pagintaionEnabled' => $pagintaionEnabled,
        ];

        return view(config('laravelusers.showUsersBlade'), $data);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $roles = [];

        if ($this->_rolesEnabled) {
            $roles = config('laravelusers.roleModel')::all();
        }

        $data = [
            'rolesEnabled'  => $this->_rolesEnabled,
            'roles'         => $roles,
        ];

        return view(config('laravelusers.createUserBlade'))->with($data);
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $rules = [
            'name'                  => 'required|string|max:255|unique:users',
            'email'                 => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password'              => 'required|string|confirmed|min:6',
            'password_confirmation' => 'required|string|same:password',
        ];

        if ($this->_rolesEnabled) {
            $rules['role'] = 'required';
        }

        $messages = [
            'name.unique'         => trans('laravelusers::laravelusers.messages.userNameTaken'),
            'name.required'       => trans('laravelusers::laravelusers.messages.userNameRequired'),
            'email.required'      => trans('laravelusers::laravelusers.messages.emailRequired'),
            'email.email'         => trans('laravelusers::laravelusers.messages.emailInvalid'),
            'password.required'   => trans('laravelusers::laravelusers.messages.passwordRequired'),
            'password.min'        => trans('laravelusers::laravelusers.messages.PasswordMin'),
            'password.max'        => trans('laravelusers::laravelusers.messages.PasswordMax'),
            'role.required'       => trans('laravelusers::laravelusers.messages.roleRequired'),
        ];

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messages);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
        }

        $user = config('laravelusers.defaultUserModel')::create([
            'name'             => $request->input('name'),
            'email'            => $request->input('email'),
            'password'         => bcrypt($request->input('password')),
        ]);

        if ($this->_rolesEnabled) {
            $user->attachRole($request->input('role'));
            $user->save();
        }

        return redirect('users')->with('success', trans('laravelusers::laravelusers.messages.user-creation-success'));
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param int $id
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $user = config('laravelusers.defaultUserModel')::find($id);

        return view(config('laravelusers.showIndividualUserBlade'))->withUser($user);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param int $id
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $user = config('laravelusers.defaultUserModel')::findOrFail($id);
        $roles = [];
        $currentRole = [];

        if ($this->_rolesEnabled) {
            $roles = config('laravelusers.roleModel')::all();

            foreach ($user->roles as $user_role) {
                $currentRole[] = $user_role->id;
            }
        }

        $data = [
            'user'          => $user,
            'rolesEnabled'  => $this->_rolesEnabled,
        ];

        if ($this->_rolesEnabled) {
            $data['roles'] = $roles;
            $data['currentRole'] = $currentRole;
        }

        return view(config('laravelusers.editIndividualUserBlade'))->with($data);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param int                      $id
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $user = config('laravelusers.defaultUserModel')::find($id);
        $emailCheck = ($request->input('email') != '') && ($request->input('email') != $user->email);
        $passwordCheck = $request->input('password') != null;

        $rules = [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
        ];

        if ($emailCheck) {
            $rules['email'] = 'required|email|max:255|unique:users';
        }

        if ($passwordCheck) {
            $rules['password'] = 'required|string|min:6|max:20|confirmed';
            $rules['password_confirmation'] = 'required|string|same:password';
        }

        if ($this->_rolesEnabled) {
            $rules['role'] = 'required';
        }

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
        }

        $user->name = $request->input('name');

        if ($emailCheck) {
            $user->email = $request->input('email');
        }

        if ($passwordCheck) {
            $user->password = bcrypt($request->input('password'));
        }

        if ($this->_rolesEnabled) {
            $user->detachAllRoles();
            $user->attachRole($request->input('role'));
        }

        $user->save();

        return back()->with('success', trans('laravelusers::laravelusers.messages.update-user-success'));
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param int $id
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $currentUser = Auth::user();
        $user = config('laravelusers.defaultUserModel')::findOrFail($id);

        if ($currentUser->id != $user->id) {
            $user->delete();

            return redirect('users')->with('success', trans('laravelusers::laravelusers.messages.delete-success'));
        }

        return back()->with('error', trans('laravelusers::laravelusers.messages.cannot-delete-yourself'));
    }

    /**
     * Method to search the users.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function search(Request $request)
    {
        $searchTerm = $request->input('user_search_box');
        $searchRules = [
            'user_search_box' => 'required|string|max:255',
        ];
        $searchMessages = [
            'user_search_box.required' => 'Search term is required',
            'user_search_box.string'   => 'Search term has invalid characters',
            'user_search_box.max'      => 'Search term has too many characters - 255 allowed',
        ];

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $searchRules, $searchMessages);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json([
                json_encode($validator),
            ], Response::HTTP_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY);
        }

        $results = config('laravelusers.defaultUserModel')::where('id', 'like', $searchTerm.'%')
                            ->orWhere('name', 'like', $searchTerm.'%')
                            ->orWhere('email', 'like', $searchTerm.'%')->get();

        // Attach roles to results
        foreach ($results as $result) {
            $roles = [
                'roles' => $result->roles,
            ];
            $result->push($roles);
        }

        return response()->json([
            json_encode($results),
        ], Response::HTTP_OK);
    }
}
```

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: Did you migrate the database successfully ? Can you check the users table and make sure you have the name field on it.

Comment: Let me see your user model and user's table migration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is a conflict in your users table and the laravel-adminlte package.

The package is trying to use the out the box laravel users table schema which has a `name` column on it.

In your migration to create the users table you are no longer creating the name column. Instead, you are creating a firstname and lastname columns.

You have two options depending on your goal.

1. You can look into publishing the packages views and change them to your schema. You may need to also update the register controller accordingly.
2. Or you can not use firstname and lastname and change it to name.

I am working on some coding samples now for this.

Answer (score 0):

I usually check if the error exist before echo any errors

```html
@if($errors->any())
<div id="error-box">
    <!-- Display errors here -->
</div>
@endif
```

or for checking specified column just put this in if statement `$errors->first('name') !== null`

Comment: I just modified my post because I had the wrong register.blade.php code, I have changed it to be the correct one. I added your error box code to the register view but it didn't return anything or show up. I presume it means there is no preexisting errors or I put it in the wrong place

Comment: Do you have any other suggestions which might help?

Comment: You need to run the command - php artisan migrate. For more details - https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations#running-migrations

Comment: I believe, you have the users table with without name the name field on it. Better if you can check your database directly from database.

Comment: I did normal PHP artisan migrate but returned nothing to migrate, so I have tried PHP artisan migrate fresh --seed. Since I've changed the name we no longer get the crash but now when the register button is clicked it just refreshes. I have an image of the network tab to show you what's going on a little. 

Here you go: https://imgur.com/Zlc0cky

I have the database set in env but don't know where the data is posting to in the registration if I can find that and see it's in there I can add the respective details. But since we aren't getting an error seems odd that it's not going in the DB

Comment: Any ideas on what I can try to fix this?